# php mysql SELECT AS with WHERE Column not found?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to use `WHERE` condition in mysql `PHP` `PDO` from `SELECT AS` , i got error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_consumers' in 'where clause'null
```

my query :

```
SELECT category.* , SUM(Consumer.capacity) AS total_consumers
FROM company AS company
RIGHT JOIN company AS Consumer ON ( Consumer.category_id = company.category_id AND Consumer.company_type = 'Consumer'  )
RIGHT JOIN category AS category ON ( category.category_id = company.category_id  )
WHERE total_consumers > 0 
GROUP BY category.category_title
```

target :

i want to get all records inc category table , and they should be exists in company table as consumer and producer , if consumer null don't select it

here is the json result of above query

if i remove the `WHERE` condition i got the below JSON response

http://json.live/166EaR

as u can see some records has `total_consumers : null` that should not be selected

any idea how to do my point :  ( why i can't use SELECT AS in WHERE statement )

```
WHERE total_consumers >  
or
WHERE total_consumers != null
or

WHERE xx NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use an alias from `select` in the `where` clause. You have to use the `having` clause:

```
SELECT category.* , SUM(Consumer.capacity) AS total_consumers
FROM company AS company
RIGHT JOIN company AS Consumer ON ( Consumer.category_id = company.category_id AND Consumer.company_type = 'Consumer'  )
RIGHT JOIN category AS category ON ( category.category_id = company.category_id  )
GROUP BY category.category_title
having total_consumers > 0
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you can use the alias, but not from an aggregate column. The WHERE limits the rows considered for aggregation, while the HAVING clause is applied after aggregation has happened.

Comment: i did the above , i got error for first one `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY category.category_title' at line 6null` and for second one Error : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group functionnull`

Comment: adding `having total_consumers > 0` after group fixed it , many thanks u made my day